# Why does this finite integral blow up in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am having some trouble understanding the output of a particular integral. I think I am misunderstanding something about how Mathematica is used, or about how the Integrate function works, and I would sincerely appreciate any insight.

When I use Mathematica, this integral gives:

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin^d(x)}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\cos ^2(x)} \sec (x) \sin ^{1-d}(x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-d}{2};\frac{3-d}{2};\sin ^2(x)\right)}{1-d}
$$

I get an infinite answer when I compute the answer for odd integer "d".  For example, $d=5$ gives ComplexInfinity.

On the other hand, if I plug $d=5$ in at the beginning, I get:

$$
\frac{1}{64} \left((3 \cos (x)-4) \csc ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+(3 \cos (x)+4) \sec ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+24 \left(\log \left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)
$$

This is a little messy, but I can use the Rubi package to get this instead:

$$
-\frac{3}{8} \tanh ^{-1}(\cos (x))-\frac{1}{4} \cot (x) \csc ^3(x)-\frac{3}{8} \cot (x) \csc (x)
$$

Neither is infinite. However, I can get around this issue by instead integrating:

$$
\int \sin ^d(x) \, dx= -\cos (x) \sin ^{d+1}(x) \sin ^2(x)^{\frac{1}{2} (-d-1)} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-d}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(x)\right)
$$

Then plugging in $d=-5$ gives the correct answer, at least when I plot it on the interval from $x \in (0, \pi)$. I don't understand why one approach gives an answer that makes sense, while the other one gives an answer that blows up at odd integers. When it blows up, it seems Mathematica is subtracting two infinite things and failing to get a finite result.

Comment: **For example, d=5  gives ComplexInfinity.** No it does not. You need to use the Limit command. Do not just plugin in values.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O07t5.png)

Comment: Thank you! Mathematica does not evaluate the limit when I take the limit command. Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

If it helps, here is the code: 

Limit[(Sqrt[Cos[x]^2]
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (1 - d)/2, (3 - d)/2, Sin[x]^2] Sec[x] Sin[
   x]^(1 - d))/(1 - d), d -> 5]

Comment: Yes, it can't evaluate the limit, which is OK, but it does not give $\infty$ which is the important part. I do not know why it can't find the Limit for $d=5$ but it can for $d=-5$.

Comment: Thank you, Nasser, for looking into this. So if the result were infinite, the limit would have returned infinity, rather than just not evaluating the answer? That is helpful to know.

Comment: Yes. Basically be careful about just plugging in values into an expression like that. It is much safer to always use Limit command (specially if the thing you are replacing is in the denominator).  even if you think it is not needed. `Limit[3*x, x -> 3]` and   `3*x /. x -> 3` both give same result.

Comment: Ah, I'm quite glad to learn this. I'll be sure to use the limit function from now on.

Comment: *Mathematica does not evaluate the limit when I take the limit command.* d->5 is a Rule that you can use with Replace or Limit; it’s not a Limit by itself.

Comment: Why does it even give complex infinity, the integral is not complex, so antiderivative should not be either. I suppose the parameter antiderivative is not correct at 5.

Comment: I think the process Mathematica uses to simplify 2F1 is going awry somewhere. I ended up doing the integral by hand, but if anyone knows where Mathematica got stuck, I would really like to know.

Thanks everyone for the help!